# How to fix Token ')' expected error in power bi?

Tags: powerbi

I am using simle dax code to create custom column, code that I am using:

```
([PTS] + [REB] + [AST] + [STL] + [BLK] −([FGA] - [FG]) − ([FTA] - [FT]) - [TOV]) / [G]
```

Error message Token ')' expected
[image]

Error is moving from A to G and vice versa. I expect to get solution or advice how to fix this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

([PTS] + [REB] + [AST] + [STL] + [BLK]) - (([FGA] - [FG]) - ([FTA] - [FT]) - [TOV])/[G]
I've made corrections to your code, can you try this?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you are not writing DAX code, since this appears to be a custom column you are adding in Power Query. The code in Power Query is called M.

To answer your question: Your syntax is wrong, since you are missing a `)` parenthesis. That is what the error message is telling you. Where that parenthesis is missing, you will have to check yourself, based on your desired calculation. Perhaps you should have an additional `)` before the division sign?